# how to sum all of rows in each row

Tags: mysql

**EDIT**:

I've used this query:

```
SELECT emp_name, position, absent, 
sum(absent), 
(SELECT (absent*100)/sum(absent) FROM employee) AS 'percentage' 
FROM employee
```

And I got only one row instead of 5.

And I made this view to see how much goals every player have:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `world_cup_2014`.`top_scorer` AS
    SELECT 
        `world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`.`team` AS `team`,
        `world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`.`player_name` AS `Player`,
        COUNT(`world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`.`player_name`) AS `Number Of Goals`
    FROM
        `world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`
    GROUP BY `world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`.`player_name`
    ORDER BY COUNT(`world_cup_2014`.`players_scored`.`player_name`) DESC
```

And it works fine:

So why in my employee table I don't get a similar result, where sum is made ?

Comment: your second query is correct, just remove the emp_name, or just select only the percentage because percentage is all you need right?

Comment: What...is...this...?  How many queries are you asking here?

Comment: so first do you want to sum all absent in a table?

Comment: first of all, try to sum all the absent in table

Comment: use my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT emp_name, position, absent,
    (SELECT SUM(absent) FROM employee) AS 'absence_sum',
    ((absent*100) / (SELECT SUM(absent) FROM employee)) AS 'percentage'
FROM employee
```

You need to use a formal subquery for the sum of absent days to avoid the RDBMS from returning a single result.

Comment: but why, in other database, I didn't use subquery and it works fine, see the edit section of my question

Comment: In your example query, you used `sum(absent)` which tells the RDBMS to return a _single_ record (AFAIK).  Whenever you use an aggregate function, it will collect all records to which it is applied into a single result.  In the case of `GROUP BY`, it will collapse each group into one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT emp_name, position, absent, 
(select sum(absent) from employee) as sum, 
(absent*100)/(select sum(absent) from employee) AS 'percentage' 
FROM employee
```

Comment: No, it gives me one row, please see my edited question one minute

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'sum' in 'field list'

Comment: ohh sorry, i did not know that it is not applicable in mysql, but in oracle aliases can use by other.